# parse a string to extract specified content in java

Tags: java, parsing

I need to extract NSID from a list of string which is stored in a file.the string look like this.
the string inside jsonFlickrApi() is in json format.

```
007rebecca@gmail.com|jsonFlickrApi({"user":{"id":"21849273@N06", "nsid":"21849273@N06", "username":{"_content":"eire5555"}}, "stat":"ok"})
```

If I want to parse this and get the nsid, in java what approach i should take.
Should I write a parser or is there any library available to parse this json inside jsonFlickrAPI()

Answer (score 1):

The string is a mix of a json and some other text. You may try to split the json part and then can use a json parser to retrieve `nsid` easily.There are various java json parsers available such as [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).